# Applying CSS Style on the Basis of Text Content?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm making an app for managing my personal tasks and as part of that, I'm populating a table using PHP that gets the rows from a MySQL database. However, since there are many tasks that are returned and each task has a status, I want to make it easier to apply different colored styling to the status of each task i.e. red for pending, yellow for in progress and so on so I can easily find them. However, I cannot seem to understand how I would go about doing this dynamically as in:

```
1. Check contents of the status cell.
2. Apply style on the basis of contents.
3. Move to next cell in status column.
4. Move to step 1.
```

Would this be done using CSS or Javascript? My guess is Javascript but I don't know where to start.

Comment: use css classes that are dependent on the `status`

Comment: @charlietfl Could you please elaborate on that?

Comment: what language are you rendering the html in?

Comment: status is a column of the table, fetched from the database, just to be clear, and it has text in it saying whether the task is complete, in progress or pending.

Comment: I'm using PHP to generate my HTML.

Comment: I would set a class depending on the status: `<td class='status in-progress'`, then `td.status.in-progress { background-color: yellow; }` PHP can do that for you by looking at the array value (which you print as the `td` status contents) and echo'ing the value into the `class` attribute. Use a function or array, like `echo "<td class='{$statuscls[$row['status']]}'>...</td>";

Comment: @JaredFarrish, I like your take on this. You mean when I'm querying the database using PHP, I should include if/else or switch/case statements to the effect of reading in the contents and then echoing them inside a span element which has the class corresponding to the element?

Comment: Not in the query, in your template. Let me mock something up.

Comment: @JaredFarrish, or that could work pretty well. Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mUapel

Comment: @JaredFarrish. Dude. You seriously rock. Respect! I really appreciate all the trouble you went through to explain this to me. It will go a long way in helping me write more sensible code. :)

I'm planning on implementing it as follows:
echo "<td class=\".$row[projStatus]."\">".$row[projStatus]."</td>";

Answer (score 0):

In php you could `str_replace()` the spaces in your `status` field with hyphen to generate the element class and have a matching set of css rules

PHP template:

```
<div class="<?= str_replace(' ', '-', $row->status);?>">
```

CSS

```
div.pending{ color:yellow }
div.in-progress{ color:orange }
```